# Checking if element in array is bigger than the previous - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with strings

```
const myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

I want to go over the array and check if the second element is bigger than the first, the third is bigger than the second and so on...

I'm using **localeCompare** to check if the string is bigger.

Thanks!

Comment: please show, what you have tried.

Comment: So loop and compare....

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean. Do you mean 'alphabetical order' with bigger? String length? Also, what should be the end result?

Answer (score 0):

```
answer=!MyArray.some((e,i)=>i?e<=MyArray[i-1]:false);
```

Checks if one of the elems (excluding the first) has one before that is bigger. If so the answer is false and dont pass the check ( i think you want to check). It requires the Array elems to be numbers, you need to change that to your needs to fit strings.

Answer (score -1):

I agree with the other comments...what are you looking for here? Can you not loop through the array and compare?

```
var myArray = ["Hello", "World", "Test", "Foo", "Br"];

for (var i = 1; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i - 1].length > myArray[i].length) {
      alert(myArray[i - 1] + " has a greater length than " + myArray[i]);
    } else if (myArray[i - 1].length < myArray[i].length) {
      alert(myArray[i - 1] + " has a smaller length than " + myArray[i]);
    } else {
      alert(myArray[i - 1] + " has the same length as " + myArray[i]);
    }
}
```